# How to represent an attribute whose type is a class that many classes inherit from?

Tags: arrays, inheritance, attributes, uml, class-diagram

I'm creating a little ORM and I have to make a class diagram using UML. How can I represent that an attribute is an array of instances of classes that inherit from a common superclass, something like this:

```
class Model {
    public attributes: string[];
}

class User extends Model {}
class Schedule extends Model {}

class Controller {
    private models: Model[] = [new User, new Schedule]
}
```

How can I model the class Controller in a UML diagram?

I did this:

[image]

But I think that is wrong because the class Controller should not have an array of Model instances, the class Controller should have an array of classes that inherit from Model.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a very basic thing you're asking. Where is your issue?

Comment: I agree with @qwerty_so. Please show us a class diagram you tried to make, even though you know it's wrong. Then we can tell you what is wrong and how it should be.

Comment: I think that the diagram is wrong because I'm not relating inherited classes, I'm relating instances of class

Comment: Thanks, Miguel, for adding the diagram. I have removed my downvote. The instances in `Model[]` may be instances of Model, but also instances of subclasses of Model, like User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A private property `model` of class `Model`, but with a multiplicity with no upper bounds can be noted as attribute:

```
- model: Model [*]
```

But you can also show it graphically, with an association, telling that each `Controller` instance may be associated with 0 or more `Model` instances:

[image: Diagram with 2 associated classes]

The `-` means `private`, the `*` is a short cut for multiplicity `0..*` meaning at minimum `0` instances and `*` for no maximum limit.

#### Edit following the edited question

In the same diagram, you may also say that `Model` can be specialized further with `User` and `Schedule` both inheriting from it:

[image]

And this corresponds to what you want to model:  it says that a `Controller` instance can be associated with 0 or more `Model` ***instances***.  But these instances do not have to be direct instances of the super class:  In UML when `User` or `Schedule` inherits from `Model`, it means that every instance of `User` or `Schedule` is also an instance of `Model`. Hence the Controller instance can be linked to schedules and users.

By the way: You could make `Model` an abstract class (Name in italic), to say that there are no direct instances of model, but only instances of its subclasses.

Comment: The OP asked about inheritance, right?

Comment: @qwerty_so I read the question:  "*How can I represent that an attribute is an array of instances of class*" And only then comes the second part "*instances that inherit from a superclass*".  So I explain how to show the array of instances of a superclass, and I leave as exercise the more obvious class inheritances, because I don't want to do the full exercise for OP.

Comment: @qwerty_so moreover, I think the difficulty seems to be the array, since OP finishes with a very specific: "*How can I diagram the class Controller?*" and there is no inheritance in the controller (neither in the question nor in the JS code).

Comment: Well, for this and other reasons I voted to close for missing clarity. Who can be helped with a not fitting question/title? And what would be an answer rather than a speculation?

Comment: @qwerty_so I see the question as rather clear in view of the quote above. The only thing that can raise criticism is the absence of a tentative diagram.  On the other hand, OP doesn't ask a full diagram but a focus on the controller.

Comment: The OP made an edit. Pretty sure you can fix your answer to match the question since his diagram is a bit flawed.

Comment: Maybe you could mention that the OP's notion of `model` is redundant (and the role notion is the preferred one). It's also bad to put the role name where the name of the association is meant to be.